# If $a_n= \int_0^1\max(x,b_{n-1})dx, b_n=\int_0^1\min(x,a_{n-1})dx$, then what is limit of $\{a_n+b_n\}$?

Tags: real-analysis

This question is found in an old question set. 
Since $\min(x,a_{n-1})\leq x$, it is clear that $b_n\leq 1/2$ and $\max(x,b_{n-1})\geq x$ we have $a_n\geq 1/2$ for every $n\geq 1$. That is, $b_n\leq 1/2 \leq a_n$ for all $n$. I feel that $\{b_n\}$ is increasing and $\{a_n\}$ is decreasing, and $\lim a_n=\lim b_n=1/2$.

Comment: Any link to the "old question set" you can provide, either online or by writing down the appropriate reference for me by editing your post? Also, have you seen similar questions before or tried out explicit values of $a_0,b_0$? Your observation is helpful.

Comment: I think according to the definitions of $a_n$ and $b_n$, for any choice of $a_0, b_0$, the answer would remain the same.

Comment: Actually, see [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1504579p8897644), apparently the answer that you think is correct is probably not, although your guess for the limit of $a_n+b_n$ is right.

Comment: The unique fixed point of the transformation $$T(a,b)=\left(\int_{0}^{1}\max(x,b)\,\mathrm{d}x, \int_{0}^{1}\min(x,a)\,\mathrm{d}x\right)$$ in the unit square $[0, 1]^2$ is $$(a,b)=(2-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}-1).$$ So, if both $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ converge in $[0, 1]$, then the answer should be $(2-\sqrt{2})+(\sqrt{2}-1) = 1$.

Comment: The unique fixed point argument then tells you that you only need to prove that $a_n,b_n$ are bounded sequences rather than monotonic ones, which you can try to prove from definition.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $a_0, b_0 \in [0, 1]$. Then it is easy to show that $a_n, b_n \in [0, 1]$ for all $n \geq 0$ and that the following recursive formula holds:

$$ a_{n+1} = \frac{1 + b_n^2}{2}, \qquad b_{n+1} = a_n - \frac{a_n^2}{2}. $$

Now define $\alpha, \beta \in [0, 1]$ by $ \alpha = 2-\sqrt{2}$ and $ \beta = \sqrt{2} - 1 $. Then

$$ \left| a_{n+1} - \alpha \right|
= \left| \frac{b_n^2 - \beta^2}{2} \right|
= \frac{b_n + \beta}{2} |b_n - \beta|
\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|b_n - \beta|, $$

ad well as

$$ \left| b_{n+1} - \beta \right|
= \left| (a_n - \alpha) - \frac{1}{2}(a_n^2 - \alpha^2) \right|
= \frac{\sqrt{2} - a_n}{2}|a_n - \alpha|
\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|a_n - \alpha|. $$

This proves that

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = \alpha = 2 - \sqrt{2}
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n = \beta = \sqrt{2} - 1. $$

Therefore it follows that

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} (a_n + b_n) = 1. $$

Comment: Thank You, Sir! Is there any simpler way to get the relations $a_{n+1}=\frac{1+b_n^2}{2}$ and $b_{n+1}=a_n-\frac{a_n^2}{2}$ and how to guess the numbers $\alpha$ and $\beta$? OR Any references for it?

Comment: @NanasahebPhatangare, For your first question, you may try to interpret each of the integrals as the area of a certain region. Then you can derive the formula only using elementary geometry. (Of course, the same answer can be obtained through pure calculus, although this will require you to split the integral according to which argument in min/max function wins.) For your second question, assume that both sequences converge and check how the recurrence relation becomes a system of equations for those limits.

Comment: Yes Sir got it. Thanks. Let $\lim a_n=x$ and $\lim b_n=y$, then we get that $x=\frac{1+y^2}{2}$ and $y=x-\frac{x^2}{2}$. Substituting one in another we get $y=1\pm x$. But $y=1+x$ is not possible because $y\leq 1/2\leq x$. Hence $y=1-x$. Substituting this in one of the above equations we get the required values.